# Sim5360e communication over UART2

Tags: lua, communication, rs485

I will implement the data exchange between the module and the device Sim5360e through UART2. I write in the Lua, AT commands to send / receive information via the UART2 did not find - so use internal devio function.

```
sio.send("AT+CSCLK=0\r\n")
readAndPrintAtUnswer()
sio.send("AT+CGFUNC=21,1\r\n")
readAndPrintAtUnswer()
sio.send("AT+IPR2=9600\r\n")
readAndPrintAtUnswer()

local msg,count=getHex(str)
local unswer
devio.open(3)
devio.write(3,msg,count)
unswer=devio.read(3,4000)
print(unswer)
devio.close(3)
```

When connected to a terminal on the PC - see the correct incoming message, the module enters the mode of reading, I send data through the terminal, but after a timeout (4000 ms) unswer = nil. Data from the terminal out exactly correct - checked by another device.

Can you please tell, how do I get an answer to my message?

Comment: did you pull down the UART's DTR? Is SPI disabled?

Comment: spi is disabled, but how to pull down UART's DTR? before execute this code - there are 3 commands: AT+CSCLK=0; AT+CGFUNC=21,1; AT+IPR2=9600

Comment: UART's DTR is pulled down too